# Unable to negate a regex in markup

Tags: regex, html, javascript

I need to validate that a string should not contain po box and should not contain special characters(only hyphen,comma and space are accepted). So, I came up with the regex :

`/^(?!.*(?:(.*((p|post)[-.\s]*(o|off|office)[-.\s,]*(box)[-.\s]*)|.*((p |post)[-.\s]*(box)[-.\s]*))))[0-9a-zA-Z\s\-\,]{1,40}$/i`

For Ex:

```
Test Po Box - Should NOT be acceptable
Test Post Office Box - Should NOT be acceptable
Test Po,Box - Should NOT be acceptable
Test PO BOx - Should NOT be acceptable
Test-123po - Should be acceptable
Test-!@$% - Should NOT be acceptable
Test123@#$ PoBOX - Should NOT be acceptable.
```

But looks like it is not working.

Any help?

Comment: Could you add some test cases, some that must match and some that mustn't?

Comment: Sure, I have edited the question

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/E5eQXx/1) what you want?

Comment: Yea, it is working in the regex online tool but the same regex is not working from the Inspect element console.

Comment: Just replace **all** `\h` with ` ` (a space). See: https://regex101.com/r/E5eQXx/2 if it works for you, I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
^(?=(?:(?!(?:post office|po)[ ,.-]?box).)*$)[\w ,.-]+$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/E5eQXx/2)

Comment: Yea, it is working as expected,Thank you so much . If possible can you suggest how can I make /^(?!.*(?:(.*((p|post)[-.\s]*(o|off|office)[-.\s,]*(box)[-.\s]*)|.*((p |post)[-.\s]*(box)[-.\s]*))))[0-9a-zA-Z\s\-\,]{1,40}$/i regex work?

Comment: @sfdc07: You're welcome, glad it helps. Your regex is very complex so it's difficult to see exactly where it fails. You can try at this [link](https://regex101.com/r/S0G5uk/1) to make t works, you will find interesting explanations.

Comment: Okay will do and Thank you so much for your help..!!